# Median Maintenance using heaps

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, heap

I'm trying to implement this problem in python3. The answer for a stream of integers from 1 to 10,000 is supposed to be 1213, which I'm not getting. I suspect there's a problem with my implementation of the heap and not the actual solution in the main() function.

Problem Statement: The goal of this problem is to implement the "Median Maintenance" algorithm. The text file contains a list of the integers from 1 to 10000 in unsorted order; you should treat this as a stream of numbers, arriving one by one. Letting xi denote the ith number of the file, the kth median mk is defined as the median of the numbers x1,…,xk. (So, if k is odd, then mk is ((k+1)/2)th smallest number among x1,…,xk; if k is even, then mk is the (k/2)th smallest number among x1,…,xk.)

Find the sum of the 10000 medians, modulo 10000.

```
#A = [4, 1, 3, 2, 16, 9, 10, 14, 8 , 7]
max_heap, min_heap = [], []
M, max_size, min_size, data_count, heap = 0, 0, 0, 0, True #True: MAX, False: MIN

def main():
    global M
    data = list(map(int, open('Median.txt').read().splitlines()))
    #data = [2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    insert(min_heap, data[0], not heap)
    M += data[0]
    insert(max_heap, data[1], heap)
    M += data[1]
    del data[:2]

    for x in data:
        if x < max_heap[0]:
            insert(max_heap, x, heap)
        else:
            insert(min_heap, x, not heap)

        if abs(max_size - min_size) > 1:
            if max_size > min_size:
                y = extract(max_heap, heap)
                insert(min_heap, y, not heap)
            else:
                y = extract(min_heap, not heap)
                insert(max_heap, y, heap)

        if (min_size + max_size)%2 == 0:
            M += max_heap[0]
        else:
            if max_size > min_size:
                M += max_heap[0]
            else:
                M += min_heap[0]
        print(max_heap, min_heap)
    print(len(max_heap), len(min_heap))
    print(M%10000)

def parent(i):
    return i//2

def left(i):
    return 2*i

def right(i):
    return (2*i) + 1

def heapify(A, i, heap):
    l, r = left(i), right(i)
    if heap:
        largest = None
        if l < max_size and A[l] > A[i]:
            largest = l
        else:
            largest = i
        if r < max_size and A[r] > A[largest]:
            largest = r

        if largest != i:
            A[i], A[largest] = A[largest], A[i]
            heapify(A, largest, heap)
    else:
        smallest = None
        if l < min_size and A[l] < A[i]:
            smallest = l
        else:
            smallest = i
        if r < min_size and A[r] < A[smallest]:
            smallest = r

        if smallest != i:
            A[i], A[smallest] = A[smallest], A[i]
            heapify(A, smallest, heap)

def buildHeap(A, heap):
    global max_size, min_size

    if heap:
        max_size = len(A)
    else:
        min_size = len(A)

    for i in reversed(range(len(A)//2)):
        heapify(A, i, heap)

def insert(A, key, heap):
    global max_size, min_size

    if heap:
        if max_size == len(A):
            A.append(key)
        else:
            A[max_size] = key
        max_size += 1
        insertUtils(A, parent(max_size), heap)
    else:
        if min_size == len(A):
            A.append(key)
        else:
            A[min_size] = key
        min_size += 1
        insertUtils(A, parent(min_size), heap)

def insertUtils(A, i, heap):
    heapify(A, i, heap)
    if parent(i) != 0:
        insertUtils(A, parent(i), heap)
    heapify(A, parent(i), heap)

def extract(A, heap): #THE PROBLEM IS HERE I BELIEVE!
    global max_size, min_size

    if heap:
        if max_size < 1:
            raise Exception('Heap underflow!')

        max = A[0]
        A[0] = A[max_size - 1]
        max_size -= 1
        heapify(A, 0, heap)
        return max
    else:
        if min_size < 1:
            raise Exception('Heap underflow!')

        min = A[0]
        A[0] = A[min_size - 1]
        min_size -= 1
        heapify(A, 0, not heap)
        return min

main()
'''
buildHeap(A, heap)
insert(A, 17, heap)
for i in range(11):
    print(A)
    print(extract(A, heap))
insert(A, 18, heap)
print(A)
print(extract(A, heap))
'''
```

I know, I'm asking a lot, it's a pretty long code. But I'll really appreciate some help! Thanks! :)

Comment: What code have you written to test this? It seems obvious to me that maintaining a list, sorting it after each number, and extracting the k/2th or k/2+1th number would be an effective check for small values (and in this case, 10000 is a small value.

Comment: @AustinHastings yes indeed but using heaps will give a better performance. We'll get an O(logn) time with heaps and O(nlogn) time with the sorting method, if we use something like quick sort. Possibly O(n) with counting sort but still heaps are better. My doubts lie in my implementation of the heaps! As for testing, I did test with very small numbers like 10, it does seem to work there. But it's not working with 10000. :/ The testing code is all there, it's commented!

Comment: If you suspect the code is in `extract`, why don't you take just that part of your code and test it to see if it's working? If the tests fail, you could replace your own definition of `heapify` with `heapq.heapify` to see if that fixes your test, and so on. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ may help.

Comment: @PaulHankin Wow! Thanks a lot for that! I have been struggling with asking the right questions actually. I try but sometimes it's just too time consuming that my daily schedule forces me to dump the code online here in hope for an answer. I'll try debugging it myself, and look into 'heapq'! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

### Startup

One problem seems to be right at the start:

```
insert(min_heap, data[0], not heap)
M += data[0]
insert(max_heap, data[1], heap)
M += data[1]
```

This code assumes that the first two items occur in decreasing order.

If the first two items are in increasing order, then your heaps will be initialized back to front, and also the second computed median will be incorrect.

### Indexing

The main problem seems to be a confusion between zero-based indexing (used in the array lookups) and one-based indexing (used in the parent/left/right functions).

Changing everything to zero-based indexing should help.
The heap functions become:

```
def parent(i):
    return (i+1)//2-1

def left(i):
    return 2*(i+1)-1

def right(i):
    return (2*(i+1))

def insertUtils(A, i, heap):
    heapify(A, i, heap)
    if parent(i) >= 0:
        insertUtils(A, parent(i), heap)

def insert(A, key, heap):
    global max_size, min_size

    if heap:
        if max_size == len(A):
            A.append(key)
        else:
            A[max_size] = key
        max_size += 1
        insertUtils(A, parent(max_size-1), heap)
    else:
        if min_size == len(A):
            A.append(key)
        else:
            A[min_size] = key
        min_size += 1
        insertUtils(A, parent(min_size-1), heap)
```

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I should've mentioned. That is indeed the case, the first two Integers are known to be in decreasing order. Once the code works, I'll change it to suit a more general situation.

Comment: I've added a description of an additional problem